# Will GRPC try a different server in a round robin when retrying?

Tags: grpc

I'm thinking of using GRPC with DNS round robin (via `dnsrr` mode of Docker swarm).  I was wondering, will it route to a different IP in the DNS-RR if it fails connecting when enableRetry() is enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round-robin DNS hides IP addresses from the client. If a connection fails to a backend gRPC will eventually re-resolve DNS and hopefully receive a new IP, but the DNS record may by cached for its full TTL so this should be seen as a slow process. Retries don't come into play here; connections have always had reconnection attempts with exponential backoff.

Retries are for RPCs and are unrelated to connections. When an RPC fails and is triggered to be retried by the retry policy specified via service config, then the RPC is simply sent again. If using client-side round-robin across multiple IPs, the retry will often go to a different server but isn't guaranteed. But if there is only one IP address returned by DNS, then retries go to the same server and will not cause DNS re-resolutions.

Note that `enableRetry()` just enables the retry subsystem (and is also the default). You probably want to specify a retry policy via service config.